# Is there a way to restrict an API on a public webserver to a specific frontend?

Tags: django, spring, rest, http, web-services

My web application has a public API endpoint eg https://example-backend/home.

I have two frontends one for internal admin (https://example-admin.com) and the other for customers (https://example.com) both using the same backend endpoint.

The goal is to allow this API to only be available to the internal admin frontend.
I thought about using the HTTP ORIGIN header which would contain the frontend URL. Is that a good approach?

Comment: This seems like a really convoluted way of solving authorization. I recommend just using Spring Security.

Comment: The authentication backend is shared. Say user1 performs a login into the app (https://example.com) and also performs a login to admin application (https://example-admin.com) how would I distinguish the two?

Comment: Ideally the admin app would have a separate web backend, but unfortunately we don't.

Comment: The point is UI and Backend should be decoupled. In that case, every endpoint can manage its permission using Spring Security. Is this helps you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check this:
[Django allowed hosts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)